# Fit multiple images of different sizes in a row of fixed width and adjust height

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox, alignment

Consider 3 (or more) images, all of different sizes and aspect ratios in a div of fixed width (for instance `width:100%`):

```
<div class="image-row">
   <img src="1.png">
   <img src="2.png">
   <img src="3.png">
</div>
```

How can you force all the images to have the same height and their total width to fill out the width of the container (i.e. how do you make a neat row of images)?

I have tried various combinations of flex or inline-block or nowrap to work properly with `height:100%` or object-fit, but nothing seems to work. I either loose the aspect ratio, cut parts of the image, or do not have equal heights.

In "English pseudocode" the procedure sounds straightforward - rescale each separately to a unit height, then rescale as a group to a given width, all while keeping aspect ratios. Is there a particular step that CSS is not capable of?

Comment: Well, using CSS alone, some either have to _loose the aspect ratio_ **or** _cut parts of the image_ if all should have equal heights and fit a given width.

Comment: @LGSon, could you explain what causes this limitation. In "English pseudocode" the procedure sounds straightforward - rescale each separately to a unit height, then rescale as a group to fixed width, all while keeping aspect ratios. Is there a particular step that CSS is not capable of?

Comment: CSS doesn't have a property that does _rescale as a group to fixed width, all while keeping aspect ratios_, for that you need a script

Answer (score 1):

I think setting the images as background images might help. That way you can have images of different sizes filling in the same width/height div using the `background-size:cover`. I don't believe it's possible to have all images be the same height without parts cutting off if the aspect ratios are different for each image. You could also try adjusting the `background-position` of each image to at least center your image in the div or try editing/cropping the photos before to have the same aspect ratio. Otherwise, you'll have to compromise.

```css
img {
  width: 33%;
  height: 150px;
}

.content {
  width: 33%;
  display:inline-block;
  height:150px;
}

#left {
  background-image: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tYBk4kLHPkk/maxresdefault.jpg");
  background-size:cover;
 
}

#center {
  background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/736x/18/f1/a7/18f1a75691c28433c0f1ef502573966b--tv-memes-office-gifs.jpg");
  background-size:cover;
}

#right {
  background-image: url("https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/bf/73/19/bf73196327b409d12c214e9994de369e--graduation-caps-grad-cap.jpg");
  background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-row">
  <div id = "left" class="content">
  </div>
  <div id = "center" class="content"> 
  </div>
  <div id = "right" class="content">
  </div>
</div>
```